# How does CUDA parallel computing work?

Tags: c, multithreading, cuda

I am pretty new to CUDA and just confused about how it works.

I have created a simple void to execute on GPU.

```
__global__ void Test (int *ch) {


long i = blockIdx.x;
ch[2] = i;
long u = threadIdx.x;
ch[3] = u;

if (i < 640)
{
    ch[0]++;

    if (u < 480)
    {

    ch[1]++;
    }

}  

}
```

I called the void with <<<640,480>>>. In all tutorials I have seen that the  If is replacing the "CPU" for-loop. The original "CPU-Void" looked like this :

```
void Test (int *ch) {

h_ch[2] = 640;
h_ch[3] = 480;

for(int a = 0;a < 640;a++)
{
    ch[0]++;

    for(int b = 0;b < 480;b++)
    {

    ch[1]++;
    }

}  

}
```

If I print the ch array generated by the CPU I will see something like this : ch[0] = 640 ch[1] = 307200 ch[2] = 640 ch[3] = 480 but what does the GPU ?

I got these results : ch[0] = 1038 (the value was changing every run!) ch[1] = 1038 (seems to be equal to ch[0]) ch[2] = 639 ch[3] = 31

What is happening ? I assumed to get the same results as on the CPU.

Thanks for answers

Below is the complete code : (I just want the same results)
You can choose either CPU or gpu

```
 #include "cuda_runtime.h"
 #include "device_launch_parameters.h"

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>

 int *h_ch , *ch;

 __global__ void Test (int *ch) 
{

long i = blockIdx.x;
ch[2] = i;
long u = threadIdx.x;
ch[3] = u;

if (i < 640)
{
    ch[0]++;
    if (u < 480)
    {

    ch[1]++;


    }

}

}
void test (int *h_ch)
{

h_ch[2] = 640;
h_ch[3] = 480;

for(int a = 0;a < 640;a++)
{
h_ch[0]++;

for(int b = 0;b < 480;b++)
{

h_ch[1]++;
}

}  

}
int main()
{
h_ch = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void **)&ch,4*sizeof(int));

h_ch[0] = 0;
h_ch[1] = 0;
h_ch[2] = 0;
h_ch[3] = 0;

cudaMemcpy(ch,h_ch,4*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//Test<<<640,480>>>(ch);
test(h_ch);

//cudaMemcpy(h_ch,ch,4*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) printf("%d ",h_ch[i]);

int a;
std::cin >> a;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a full example that will compile and include information about your desired result.

Comment: You have multiple threads stepping on each other as they try to update the two locations `ch[0]` and `ch[1]`.  In the GPU, multiple threads are executing in parallel.  When all of these threads try to update the same location at the same time, there is chaos.  If you want to see this code work properly, replace your ordinary updates (e.g. `ch[1]++;`) with atomic updates (e.g. `atomicAdd(ch+1, 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues.

1. You have multiple threads stepping on each other as they try to update the two locations `ch[0]` and `ch[1]`. In the GPU, multiple threads are executing in parallel. When all of these threads try to update the same location at the same time, there is chaos. If you want to see this code work properly, replace your ordinary updates (e.g. `ch[1]++;`) with atomic updates (e.g. `atomicAdd(ch+1, 1);`
2. Your GPU code and CPU code are not the same, logically.  Your GPU code has each thread updating `ch[0]` and `ch[1]` once, so the end numbers in these locations should be 640 and 480, respectively, if the issue in #1 above were addressed.  But your CPU code has the update of `ch[1]` being performed in a loop, 480 times for each update of `ch[0]`.  We could fix this by modifying the GPU code to be like the CPU code, or vice-versa by modifying the CPU code to be like the GPU code, logically.

The following code has the above 2 issues addressed, modifying the CPU code to be like the GPU, with expected results of 307200 in both `ch[0]` and `ch[1]` for both CPU and GPU:

```
$ cat t609.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int *h_ch , *ch;

__global__ void Test (int *ch)
{

  long i = blockIdx.x;
  long u = threadIdx.x;

  if (i < 640)
    atomicAdd(ch,1);
  if (u < 480)
    atomicAdd(ch+1,1);
}

void test (int *h_ch)
{

  for(int a = 0;a < 640;a++)
    for(int b = 0;b < 480;b++){
      h_ch[0]++;
      h_ch[1]++;}

}
int main()
{
  h_ch = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&ch,4*sizeof(int));

  h_ch[0] = 0;
  h_ch[1] = 0;
  h_ch[2] = 0;
  h_ch[3] = 0;

  cudaMemcpy(ch,h_ch,4*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  Test<<<640,480>>>(ch+2);
  test(h_ch);

  cudaMemcpy(h_ch+2,ch+2,2*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++) printf("%d \n",h_ch[i]);

  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t609 t609.cu
$ ./t609
307200
307200
307200
307200
$
```